# How can I return all the rows from my database

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite

I need to create a function in python that returns all rows in my sqllite database.

I have created this function but it returns only the first row of my table.

```
import sqlite3
def data_provider():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('MainDatabase.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sqlstr = 'SELECT * FROM Products_table'
    for row in cur.execute(sqlstr):
        return row
print(data_provider())
```

Comment: Are you aware of the `.dump` command of the sqlite commandline tool? If no read up on it. If yes, please explain what you need different. E.g. why do want to do it via Python. I cannot imagine any use case for wanting all rows in all tables, which cannot be served by the dump.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `yield` instead of `return`?  And then `for row in data_provider(): print(row)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only getting one row returned because your code is literally returning the first result of the row generator:

```
import sqlite3
def data_provider():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('MainDatabase.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sqlstr = 'SELECT * FROM Products_table'
    for row in cur.execute(sqlstr):
        return row                     # <- This is the one row you're returning because 'return' is causing execution to leave the loop
print(data_provider())
```

If you want to return all rows as a Python list, you can you the fetchall() method on the cursor like this:

```
import sqlite3
def data_provider():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('MainDatabase.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sqlstr = 'SELECT * FROM Products_table'
    cur.execute(sqlstr)
    return cur.fetchall()
print(data_provider())
```